# Pouring concrete slab around wood posts of covered porch

Tags: concrete, post, slab, footings, porch

I have a covered back porch.  Sloped roof attached to the house on one end and supported by four 4x4's which are cemented in the ground on the other end (I assume there are cement footers below the soil.  This was done by the previous owner).

I want to remove the existing pavers and pour a concrete slab as my floor.  Are there any dangers to having it poured around the wooden posts holding up the porch roof?  Do I need to protect them somehow before the pour?

Comment: Almost.  Mine would be covered with a roof and my posts go all the way into the ground and don't have the footings sticking up out of the ground like that one does.  I guess my question is - would pouring concrete around the wood posts themselves be harmful to the posts?

Comment: The suggestions in the accepted answer there all apply. I'd wrap your posts with something like sill seal (1/4" roll foam) and do your pour. Trim off the foam at slab level later.